# vim using line back in register

Tags: vim, vi

I would like to register this:

```
a

b
```

So I typed `:` then  `let @c='a^Mb'` and I tried also with `\r` and `\n` instead of `^M`

When I type `"cp` vim do not consider this as a return to line but as chars.

**Update**:

I am running vim 7.4.52 on 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:let @c="a\n\nb"
```

Seems to be working fine for me on vim7.4 on FreeBSD.  (Double quotes instead of single quotes)

If it's not working, you might want to specify which platform and version of vim?

Comment: I am running vim 7.4.52 on 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu

Comment: I also run vim 7.4.52 on ubuntu 14.04 and this solution with the \n worked for me. run vim with an empty vimrc just to make sure: `vim -u /dev/null`. Also `:reg` show this on my machine: `"c   a^J^Jb`.

Comment: Found the answer, I should use " " instead of ' '.